# Running multile sql statment in one transaction using myBatis

Tags: mysql, sql, mapping, mybatis

When trying to run multiple queries like:

```
 <insert id="insertTest">
 insert into table1 values('foo'); 
 insert into table2 values('foo');
 </insert>
```

using myBatis I get exception with sql error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax ... at line 2
```

I have tried various combination of the following settings, all returned same result.

```
## JDBC connection properties.
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?allowMultiQueries=true
username=root
password=********

# If set to true, each statement is isolated
# in its own transaction.  Otherwise the entire
# script is executed in one transaction.
auto_commit=false

# This controls how statements are delimited.
# By default statements are delimited by an
# end of line semicolon.  Some databases may
# (e.g. MS SQL Server) may require a full line
# delimiter such as GO.
delimiter=;
full_line_delimiter=false

# This ignores the line delimiters and
# simply sends the entire script at once.
# Use with JDBC drivers that can accept large
# blocks of delimited text at once.
send_full_script=true
```

settings from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380201/running-multiple-mysql-statements-in-one-transaction-in-mybatis-migration-tool)

Comment: The settings look ok. Maybe the problem is in the second insert statement itself?

Comment: This only demo insert, I tried other quires. no matter how you switch them you get the same sql error

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the column name missing into which you want to insert the data?

```
insert into table1 (column_name) values('foo');
```

Comment: No, in fact this is only demo query, whatever queries you try you will get error on the second one.